# Three questions about ω and Ω functions(Number Theory).

Tags: number-theory

I have $3$ questions related to two functions, which are called $Ω(n)$ and $ω(n)$.

The definition:

Let us have an $n$ positive integer in its' prime factor form: $p_1^{l_1}*...*p_r^ {l_r}$.

In that case, $ω(n)=r$(the number of different prime divisors), $Ω(n)=l_1+l_2+...l_r$(sum of the exponents).

For example: $12=2^2*3^1 \rightarrow ω(12)=2, Ω(12)=2+1=3$.

Here are some things I need to solve:

- For what $n$ positive integer is it true, that $ω(n)=Ω(n)$?
- Prove, that for every $n$ positive integer: $Ω(n) \le \log_2 n$. When does equality stand?
- Give the inverse function of $ω(n)$ and $Ω(n)$

For the first question: I found some good examples: Prime numbers are definitely good, since $ω(p)$ will always be $1$, and $Ω(n)$ must be $1$ too. I think that any numbers, which don't have an exponent greater than $1$, are good for this example, but can't prove, why I can't have any more solutions.

I have an idea for the second question: Equality stands if $n=2^k$, it is easy to show that. For other numbers, equality cannot stand, since $log_2 n$ won't be in a integer if $n$ is not a power of $2$. I don't know how to prove the first part of the question.

And I am quite lost in the last question, I have no idea how I should get back any $n$ only from these functions.

If you can help with any of these $3$, it is very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the inverse for question $3$? $\omega$ and $\Omega$ are not injective.

Comment: I am not sure if I wrote it correctly, but the task says to give the inversion of these functions, and I have seen a theorem that every number-theory functions have that(I am not sure what I write is correct), but I understand your point, thats why I was stuck. :/

Comment: Could it possibly mean Mobius inversion?

Comment: It could be. :)

Comment: Feel free to edit it in order to make it correct. :)

Comment: Are you familiar with what mobius inversion means? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_inversion_formula)

Comment: About the second question, you can conclude your argument observing that for every fixed $k$, $2^{k}$ is the smallest number such that $\Omega\left(n\right)=k$.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with it, I got this as homework, but we didn't learn that. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, assume for a contradiction that $\omega(n)=\Omega(n)$, where $n=p_1^{a_1}\ldots p_r^{a_r}$, where the $p_i$ are all distinct primes, and at least one of the $a_i$ is greater than 1. Then $\Omega(n)=\sum a_i \geq 2+1+\ldots+1$, with $r-1$ ones in the summation. But this is greater than or equal to $r+1$ which is greater than $r$, which is $\omega(n)$ by definition.

Comment: Understandable, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question, let $n=\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}p_i^{e_i}$. We have
$\Omega(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}e_i$. Hence
$$
\Omega(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}e_i=\omega(n)
$$
if and only if all $e_i=1$, i.e., $n$ is the product of distinct primes. The second question has been answered already.
For the third question, since $\Omega(1)=\omega(1)=0$, both functions have no Dirichlet inverse (because we must have $1=f(1)g(1)$ if $f$ is the Dirichlet inverse of $g$).

Comment: Very solid proof!

Comment: @Atvin Thank you. I hope it is helpful.